# PowerShell WMI query failure over time

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, wmi

I am performing PowerShell (4.0) WMI query as below to obtain a specific process ID for java processes, the process variable is effectively 'java' and command is part of the path to a know part of the command line value (java command line options).

`(Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name like '%$process%' and commandLine like '%$command%' and not commandline like '%shutdown%'")`

This, given a unique command line should always return a single process/process id value.

The PowerShell is called originally from a Scheduled Task that then enters into an infinite loop calling the WMI query every X minutes, this works for ~1 hour after I log off from the server and then simply stops returning the process. Logging back onto the server I can then open a new PS shell and run the command manually - it works, the task running in task manager continues to show no values.

If I am logged onto the server with a PowerShell ISE window open and configure an infinite loop to do the same while remaining logged in this does not suffer the same situation and the loop seems to continue without failure - but the key difference here is I can not log off from the server as I have an interactive shell open - I think from testing the scheduled task also does not fail while the interactive session is active.

The scheduled task is called as a local admin account running with highest privs with the password stored.

Any ideas why the WMI query stops after a period of time and how this may be corrected as I can not rely on keeping my RDP session active?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible that after you logoff, the process gets killed after a while? Since your WMI query is doing filters, it would simply return nothing instead of erroring out. You could however, break up ur code, log the processes returned and then do a filter on it using `where-object` and troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi, I have configured a basic 'out-file' output and can monitor this from a remote server by UNC path - I can see that the log file is constantly appended to as expected from loop that is in place - so the loop is running. Also when I do re-connect I can see the process in Task Manager - other areas of the loop performing other activities are still working/recording in log files as expected - seems to be just the WMI query. I have also used a -Query rather than -Filter with hard coded values - they all stopped working at the same time almost exactly 1 hour from logging off from the server.

Comment: I have added another output `(Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from in32_process").count` and will restart the process, will update in an hour!

Comment: The count value stopped reporting the value (at the same time as the other WMI queries), this time it was after about 12 minutes, but the WMI query above to get the count of processes was reporting 60-70 processes and now reports 0 from the loop.

Comment: Okay. so what i am gathering is that the WMI query stops returning anything at all. You said ur scheduled task runs this in an infinite loop. I assume it is triggered once per day? Make sure the security Options in General tab of the task has `Run whether user is logged on or not` and in Settings tab, `Stop the task if it runs longer than` is set to more than an hour. Alternately, you can change the trigger to run every hour also.

Comment: Hi Sid, the task is set to run logged on and off, and set to terminate if more than 3 days old. The way this is Scheduled Task is called is a little more complicated than probably described, The Scheduled Task executes on the hour every hour to make sure that the looping script is present/running, if not it creates a new instance of the loop script - this Scheduled Task script executes and exits after creating the loop script. I can see from the WMI information that the CreationDate on the Powershell loop script that it was created when I last killed and restarted the tasks on Friday 13th.

Comment: This appears to happen when a Windows event (security) event 4624 or 4648 happens in eventvwr

Comment: I have worked around this with a simple 'if the WMI query fails' check for (Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from Win32_process").count if this is 0 then it restarted the entire process (as this should never be 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around this with a simple 'if the WMI query fails' check for (Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from Win32_process").count if this is 0 then it restarted the entire process (as this should never be 0)